# nginx rewrite if file exist

Tags: php, nginx

My script modifies image and returns the result.

I want to process the image only if it exists.

However the following block won't work, nginx just returns the original image.

```
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png)$ {
    if (-f $uri) {
        rewrite (.*) /imagemagic.php?src=$1 last;
    }
}
```

I initially used this inside the script to check, however I don't like it sitting in the script file...

```
if (!file_exists($_GET['src'])) {
    http_response_code(404);
    exit();
}
```

How am I supposed to do this using nginx settings? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-f` operator requires a pathname, use `$document_root` or `$request_filename`.

For example:

```
if ( -f $document_root$uri ) { ... }
```

Or:

```
if ( -f $request_filename ) { ... }
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) for details.